# How to get real video url through html5 <video> tag?

Tags: html, video

I want to get the real url of a video embeded with `<video>`,`<object>`,`<embed>` tag.

For example https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Th9nu3RDwEM ,i use Chrome' Dev Tools and find the `<video>` tag and it's `"src"` attribute is:

blob:https%3A//www.youtube.com/9ceed388-a540-4857-85d4-a1538276dc45.

But when i type this into browser,nothing happens.

So i want to know is there any ways to get the real url ? And since `"src"` is not the real video url, what does it mean?

Comment: you would have to watch network traffic to see what's being requested.

Comment: That is i have to check the website one by one in order to know the request but no general way? And what does "src" really mean?